# Hibernate configuration file : Archive for required library persistence.xml cannot be read

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, maven, corrupt

I tried all answers I found on stackoverflow but no one suits my problem :

> Archive for required library:
>   'src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml' in project 'project'
>   cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file

[image: errors]

My hibernate configuration file "persistence.xml" is in the folder META-INF directly in src/main/resources but Eclipse continues to tell me that there is a build path problem.

Here the content :

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
   <persistence-unit name="app.shellx.jpa">
<!--       <jta-data-source>java:/DefaultDS</jta-data-source> -->
      <properties>
         <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect"/>
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>        
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and the persistence.xml is explicitly added to the build path :

[image: buildpath]

Moreover, Eclipse prints a lots of error pop-up I can't coding like that.

Comment: You don't have to add it as a library (it isn't one), just leave it in your resource folder and see if it works

Comment: I don't know why it didn't work before but you solved my problem.. I feel so dumb.

Comment: I'll move my comment to an answer then, please accept it so other people can find it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to add it as a library, just leave it in your resource folder.